# MYSQL regular expression matching any word in between square brackets

Tags: mysql, regex

I have to find all the values of a specific column in a table where the column values match like [name]

I should not get the values that are like [a]+[b] or [a]>[b] or [a]%[b]=[c]

So I basically do not need column values that have special characters in them except the square brackets and under score

example: [test_123] should be returned.

I tried

`select * from table_name where column_name REGEXP '^[[][^+-></%]';`

This is just trying to see if there is any special character immediately after [ but how to see if there is any special character in the whole column value and should we give backslashes to define special characters in MySQL?

I tried in https://regexr.com/ and I have got my required Regex to be

`(\[)\w+[^\+\=\/\*\%\^\!](\])`

but I could not do the same in MySQL

Comment: Please provide some strings that should be returned, and some that should not.  I am, for example, unclear whether square brackets are part of the string or meta information.  And is `a` literal or standing for any single letter or standing for any alphabetic string or alphanumeric string.  And whether underscore is included in "alphanumeric".  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

*** UPDATED **

```
(\[[^\_]+])+
```

That seems to work for what you're looking for.

Also your query is wrong, I believe it is supposed to look like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(mycolumn, 'regexp', 'i');
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but after running the first one I got empty set so ran the second one I have got output but still it is not what I am expecting. I still got values that are like [test_field]+1 ,  ([a] *[b])/100 I need only values that are [test1234] or [abcdef] or [Sample_123]

Comment: I do not know the reason but even this did not work but I tried answer as`'^[[.left-square-bracket.]]+([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[_]|[[.left-square-bracket.]]|[[.right-square-bracket.]])+[[.right-square-bracket.]]$';`